# Java Student Mark Categorizing into Odd and Even

Tags: java

Create class `Student` with below attributes:
`rollNo, Name, Marks`

Create class `StudentDemo` with `main` method.

Declare array of 5 student objects in `main` method. Initialize this array.

Declare another method in this class – `splitStudentArray`. This method will take the `student` array and a character as input parameters.

If the input character is ‘o’ this method will return array of students with odd value of marks. If the input character is ‘e’ then this method will return array of students with even value or marks. It will return null array if there is any other character specified.

Display `name` and `marks` for this returned array from `main` method.

Comment: How do you want to split by `rollNo` or `Marks`?

Comment: the odd/even should be categorized by Marks. Then this categorized mark array should give students rollno and name respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following `StudentDemo.java`:

```
public class StudentDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student st1 = new Student(1, "abhi", 200.5);
        Student st2 = new Student(2, "maggie", 200);
        Student st3 = new Student(3, "suraj", 107);
        Student st4 = new Student(4, "naveen", 249);
        Student st5 = new Student(5, "jajan", 101);

        Student[] sts = { st1, st2, st3, st4, st5 };
        System.out.println("splitStudentArray : " + java.util.Arrays.toString(splitStudentArray(sts, 'o')));
    }

    private static Student[] splitStudentArray(Student[] sts, char ch) {
        if (ch == 'o') {
            System.out.println("number is odd");
            return oddArray(sts); // create function or insert for loop here
        } else if (ch == 'e') {
            System.out.println("number is even");
            return evenArray(sts); // create function or insert for loop here
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Student[] oddArray(Student[] sts) {
        java.util.List<Student> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Student>();
        for (Student student : sts) {
            if (student.getMarks() % 2 != 0) {
                list.add(student);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new Student[0]);
    }

    private static Student[] evenArray(Student[] sts) {
        java.util.List<Student> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Student>();
        for (Student student : sts) {
            if (student.getMarks() % 2 == 0) {
                list.add(student);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new Student[0]);
    }

    private static class Student {
        private int rollNo;
        private String Name;
        private double Marks;

        public Student(int rollNo, String name, double marks) {

            this.rollNo = rollNo;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Marks = marks;
        }

        public int getRollNo() {
            return rollNo;
        }

        public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
            this.rollNo = rollNo;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }

        public double getMarks() {
            return Marks;
        }

        public void setMarks(double marks) {
            Marks = marks;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student [rollNo=" + rollNo + ", Name=" + Name + ", Marks=" + Marks + "]";
        }       

    }
}
```

and tell me whether it works for you or not?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.